# How do I manually generate a base58 private key from my secret spendkey?

Tags: privatekey, spend-key

What are the steps for deriving a base58 private key from a secret spendkey?  Sort of like the answer here, but for Monero or another Cryptonote: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8247/how-can-i-convert-a-sha256-hash-into-a-bitcoin-base58-private-key

Answer (score 1):

Monero has some base58 functions in src/common/base58.*.
If for some reason you wanted to store your secret keys as base58, you could use those. There are usage examples in tests/unit_tests/base58.cpp.

Comment: I'd just add, this link details Monero's implementation with reference. https://monerodocs.org/cryptography/base58/